# Add character(s) to value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Table, TextArea and Button, when a user type in the Textarea such as " Hello World! " and then clicks on the button I want the text to become  " Hello World! (*) ".

How can I do that with this Jquery code that I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#Button').click(function () {
         if ($("#MyTextArea").val().indexOf('|') > -1) {
             alert("The box has special characters. \nThese are not allowed.\n");
         } else {
             if ($.trim($("#MyTextArea").val()).length > 0) {
                 $('#MyTable tbody').append(
                 $('<tr/>', {
                     click: function () {
                         $(this).remove()
                     },
                     html: $("<td />", {
                         html: $("#MyTextArea").val(),
                         'data-sharp-id': 8
                     })
                 }));
                 return false;
             }
         }
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
html: $("#MyTextArea").val(),
```

to

```
html: $("#MyTextArea").val() + "(*)",
```

Answer (score 1):

So are the special chars ( * ) allowed in the textbox? Or do you want to SEND value+(*) to the server without showing it?

If the former then

```
$('#Button').click(function () {
  var val =$("#MyTextArea").val(); 
  if (val.indexOf('(*)')==-1) $("#MyTextArea").val(val+"(*)");
  if (val.indexOf('|') > -1) {

.
.
.
```

if the latter, see [@ManseUKs solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10107820/295783)